# Detail Button cant send data within ajax pagination

Tags: jquery

i have a script which i am using for ajax pagination

the script also runs well,

let me share the script with u all

```
function show_tour_type(v,t)
{
    $(".cl_tour_type").html('<div align="center"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/front_assets/images/ajax-loader-large.gif" align="center" style="max-height: 300px; max-width: 300px; min-height: 300px;" alt="image" /></div>');
    var p=v;
    var showresult='';
    var showpagi='';
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url().'ajax/ajax_tour_type_pagination';?>",
        data:{'start':p,'perpage':t},
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        async:true,
        success:function(result){
            pagi = result.pagi;
            uname = result.uname;
            console.log(pagi.cont.perpage);
            result= result.content;
            console.log(result);

            for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
            {
                showresult+='<div class="tour_type_ajax"><h1>'+result[i].tour_type+'</h1><br/><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+result[i].type_image+'" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 180px; min-height: 100px;" alt="image" /><br/><br/><br/><div class="detail_button"><input type="text" id="tour_type'+i+'" value="tour_type'+i+'"/><a href="#!/page_tour_specification" onclick="show_tour_spec('+result[i].tour_type+')">Detail</a></div></div>';
            }
            //showresult+='<div class="cleaner_with_width">&nbsp;</div><div class="cleaner_with_height">&nbsp;</div><div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div><div class="cleaner_with_height">&nbsp;</div>';
            showpagi+='<table width="20%" height="100%" border="0"><tr>';
            for(i=0;i<pagi.cont.pages;i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                    showpagi+='<td onclick="show_tour_type('+parseInt(i)+','+pagi.cont.perpage+')"><a href="javascript:void(0);">First</a></td>';
                else if(i==pagi.cont.pages-1)
                    showpagi+='<td onclick="show_tour_type('+parseInt(i)+','+pagi.cont.perpage+')"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Last</a></td>';
                else
                    showpagi+='<td onclick="show_tour_type('+parseInt(i+1)+','+pagi.cont.perpage+')"><a href="javascript:void(0);">'+parseInt(i+1)+'</a></td>';
            }

            showpagi+='</tr></table>';
            $(".cl_tour_type").html(showresult);
            $(".pagenav").html(showpagi);
        }
    });
}


function hii(val)
{
    alert(val);
}
```

now i am facing a problem that is quite weird,

in the line

```
 showresult+='<div class="tour_type_ajax"><h1>'+result[i].tour_type+'</h1><br/><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+result[i].type_image+'" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 180px; min-height: 100px;" alt="image" /><br/><br/><br/><div class="detail_button"><input type="text" id="tour_type'+i+'" value="tour_type'+i+'"/><a href="#!/page_tour_specification" onclick="hii('+result[i].tour_type+')">Detail</a></div></div>';
```

u can find the code `onclick="hii('+result[i].tour_type+')"`

which is supposed to call the function `hii(val)`

now the problem is that the function hii is called but it doesnt alert anything;

but in the line if i simple write `+2+` in place of `+result[i].tour_type+`

then its alerting 2

so that means the function is correct,

what the problem is that may be `+result[i].tour_type+` has some issues.

but then i wonder, if this doesnt have any value, then it wudnt have been displayed in the ajax responce.. so it returns a value... then why doesnt it send the value in `hii` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because you're passing in the literal string. Wrap quotes around it like so.

```
'...onclick="hii(\''+ result[i].tour_type +'\')"...'
```

Without the quotes it would be evaluated like this `hi(somevalue)`. `somevalue` isn't a variable and therefore won't work.

The reason `'hi('+ 2 +')'` works is because `2` is evaluated as an integer rather than a string.

Comment: Thank You vai.... thats the thing which solved my problem..... no matter as soon as 8 minutes are passed, i am gonna accept ur answer... stackoverflow isnt letting me accept it before 8 mins

Comment: I understand the limitations - glad to have helped.